# reachability issue when open my app. Swift

Tags: swift, alert, appdelegate, reachability, internet-connection

My reachability function is executed if I open my app with internet. So, if I turn off the wifi, alert would be displayed. But, it doesn't work if I open my app with no internet. No alert is displayed. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var reachability: Reachability?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "checkForReachability:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
        self.reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
        self.reachability!.startNotifier()

    }

    func checkForReachability(notification: NSNotification) {
        let remoteHostStatus = self.reachability!.currentReachabilityStatus()
        if (remoteHostStatus.rawValue == NotReachable.rawValue) {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please check your internet connection.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Try again.", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                action in
                self.checkForReachability(notification)
            }
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you open the app when there is no connection, no reachability change occurs.  Since it never transitions from unknown/not reachable to reachable, you won't see a notification.

Comment: Is there any way to check the internet connect first when I open my app?

Comment: I am thinking to call the checkForReachability function from my initial view controller to check the internet connection. Does it make sense to do it? If yes, what variable should I pass into this function?